# Unable to import 'pyspark' pylint(import-error) on Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark, python-import, lint

Having a simple functioning spark program in VS Code editor, spark-submit the pyspark code was working fine with expected results. I thought it was missing VS ext for Python but it isn't. Any one had similar errors with pylint. The "Unable to import" part seems serious but if it was a linting package perhaps no big deal. Irritating nonetheless. [image: VS code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX7Hr.png)

Comment: Are you using pipenv or other similar virtualization? have you installed the pyspark?

Comment: No pipenv. I have pyspark 2.4.5